# Why won't this mesh let itself be weight painted?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

For some reason, this Mesh won't let itself be weight painted. No matter what I do, I can't really paint more weights on it, specially not in face mask mode which I kinda need.

Does anybody know why?

Sample file: https://a.pomf.cat/wtlzlh.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two reasons:

- Mode is face selection masking: so you need to select faces (<kbd>A</kbd> or right click select)
- The setting is to subtract and there is no weight to subtract

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Do you have any idea why it won't paint when the "limit selection to visible" setting is switched?

Comment: Yes, because some normals are inverted (back facing)

Comment: I see, do you know how I could invert them?

Comment: To do it easily... no. Doing it face per face... : (. This often occurs with garments (because what is front becomes back when you fold it) and this is not so easy to handle.

Comment: Oh wow, I see. Thanks! This was a really really nice learning project for me and you helped me finish it! :)